# Who carries the 2nd and 3rd Sefer Torah?

Tags: sources-mekorot

In the synagogue that I attend I was asked to carry the 2nd Sefer the Chazan 1st to the Bimah. Afterwards the other gentleman who I had pesicha with took the 1st Sefer back. The chazan takes the Maftir back.

Why is this? I was under the impression that whoever does hagbah takes the Sefer back except one which is given to the Chazan in this case the maftir.

Any mekomos that the one who didn’t take to the Bimah now takes it to the Aron.

Otherwise how would it work when Rosh Chodesh Chanukah and shabbos fall?

Comment: From what I have seen - the Chazan carries the 1st one and the others are given to anyone the shul wishes. Rarely are the others the one's doing hagbah or gelilah. And, usually, the ones who carried one to the bimah, carry the same ones back to the aron. Of course, exceptions and leniencies are around for the chazzanim that cannot carry a Torah themselves.

Comment: Thanks. But looking for sources as to why various Shuls does this or that way.

Comment: You **may** be able to find a source. I am not aware of any specific halacha or minhag mentioned anywhere regarding who should get which Torah other than the 1st which goes to the Chazzan. Thus, I think what each shul does with the others is really up to them. The shul I was in as a child needed 10 people to carry 2 Sifrei Torah, and they used 2 different people to carry them back. (Mind you, of course only 2 carried - the others had different assignments, even if it meant just standing and "supervising".)

Comment: Unlikely you'll find anything but very recent "sources" for customs that are unrelated to Halacha. Another case of "do whatever is sensible".